# Questions regarding code in a Data Structures and Algorithms book

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, big-o

I have been refreshing my knowledge of data structures and algorithms using a book. I came across some sample code in the book, including some run time analysis values that I cannot seem to make sense of. I don't know if I am overthinking this or I am missing something extremely simple. Please help me out.

1. This is the case where they explain the logic behind adding an element at a specific index in a list. I get the logic, it is pretty simple. Move all the elements, starting with the rightmost one, one index to the right to make space for the element at the index. The code for this in the book is given by:

   `for j in range(self._n, k, −1): 
       self._A[j] = self._A[j−1]`

   What I do not get is the range of the loop. Technically, `self._n` is equivalent to `len(list)` (an internal state maintained by the list). And if you start at `len(list)`, you are immediately at an `IndexOutOfBoundError`. Secondly, even if that were not true, the loop replaces `n` with `n-1`. Nowhere does it actually move `n` to `n+1` first, so that value is lost. Am I missing something here?  I actually tried these conditions out on the Python interpreter and they seem to validate my understanding.
2. Some of the run time analyses for list operations seems to confuse me. For example:
   `data.index(value) --> O(k+1)
   value in data --> O(k+1)
   data1 == data2 (similarly !=, <, <=, >, >=) --> O(k+1)
   data[j:k] --> O(k−j+1)`

   I do not get why the `+1` at the end of each running time analysis. Let us consider the `data.index(value)` operation, which basically returns the first index at which a certain value is found. At the worst case, it should iterate through all `n` elements of the list, but if not, if the search finds something at index `k`, then it returns from there. Why the `O(k+1)` there? The same logic applies to the other cases too, especially the list slicing. When you slice a list, isn't it just `O(k-j)`? On the contrary, the actual indices are `j` to `k-1`.

This understanding should be quite elementary and I really feel silly not being able to understand it. Or I don't know if there are genuine errata in the book and I understand it correctly. Could someone please clarify this for me? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the book?

Comment: @Nelfeal : Data Structures and Algorithms in Python by Goodrich, Tamassia and Goldwasser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note (from the comments): the book in question is [Data Structures and Algorithms in Python by Goodrich, Tamassia and Goldwasser](https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/python/Data%20Structures%20and%20Algorithms%20in%20Python%20[Goodrich,%20Tamassia%20&%20Goldwasser%202013-03-18].pdf), and the questions are about pages 202 to 204.

If you actually look at the whole definition of `insert` from the book, it makes more sense.

```
def insert(self, k, value):
    if self.n == self.capacity:
        self.resize(2 * self.capacity)

    for j in range(self.n, k, −1):
        self.A[j] = self.A[j−1]

    self.A[k] = value
    self.n += 1
```

The first line implies that `self.n` is the number of elements, and corresponds to the index past-the-end, which means that, for a user of the list, accessing it at that index would be erroneous. But this code belongs to the list, and because it has a capacity in addition to a size, it can use `self.A[n]` if `self.n < self.capacity` (which is true when the for loop starts).

The loop simply moves the last element (at index `n-1`) to the next space in memory, which is out of bounds for a user, but not internaly. At the end, `n` is incremented to reflect the new size, and `n-1` becomes the index of that "next space in memory", which now contains the last element.

As for the time complexity of the different operations: well, they are not incorrect. Even though `O(n+1) = O(n)`, you can still write `O(n+1)` if you want to, and it might be more "precise" in some cases.

For example, it is written that `data.index(value)` has a complexity of `O(k+1)`, with `k` the index of the value being search for. Well, if that value is at the very beginning, then `k = 0` and the complexity is `O(0+1) = O(1)`. And it's true: if you always search for a value that you know is at the very beginning, even though this operation is pointless, it has a constant time complexity. If you initially wrote `O(k)` instead, then you would get `O(0)` for that last operation, which I have never seen used, but would make me think that the operation is instantaneous.

The same thing happens for slicing: they probably wrote `O(k−j+1)` because if you only take one element, then `j = k` and the complexity is `O(1)` instead of `O(0)`.

Note that time complexity isn't usually defined in terms of the actual indices of a particular application of the function, but instead in terms of the total number of elements in the container on which the function is used. You can think of it as the mean complexity for using the function with every possible index, which in the cases of `index` and slicing, is simply `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Guess I misread the code with respect to the actual capacity and length of the list. Thought I was missing something very elementary and did not believe that the book could have made such a fundamental error. Also, appreciate the clarification on the running time. That makes much more sense now as to why they denote it with the `+1` rather than just the index. As for your last point, I was quite certain that it was `O(n)`, but just wanted to double check the reasoning that they were using.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, I think the assumption is that you have a list of fixed maximum length and you are supposed to lose the last datapoint. Also, are you certain that `self._n == len(n)` and not `self._n == len(n)-1`?

For the second case, as far as I understand, O(k+1) is the same as O(k), so it doesn't make sense to say O(k+1). But again if we really want to know how someone may count up to k+1... I would guess that guy is counting starting from 0. So to go from 0th to the kth index will take k+1 operations.

This is just an opinion, and an uniformed one, so please take it with a tablespoon of salt. I think that book is no good man.

Comment: Nope, for the first one. The book is Data Structures and Algorithms in Python and a pretty popular one. The discussion is about Python Dynamic Referential Lists. There is no fixed list and no dropping of the last value. That is why it is not making any sense to me. On the second thing, that is also what I thought, in general, the bound on the run time in dominated by the higher order value, so why the constant in there? But what you say actually does make sense, maybe that is the way they are denoting it.

Comment: well in that case, you have already confirmed that the code is wrong by converting it to actual python programs. Don't worry about it. You are right... it seems.